# How to define a JUnit method rule in a test suite?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a class that is a JUnit suite of JUnit test classes. I would like to define a rule *on the **suite*** to do something to the database before and after each unit test is run *if* a certain annotation is present on that test method.

I've been able to create a [`@ClassRule`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/ClassRule.html) in the suites and test classes that will do this before each and every *class* (which is not good enough) and I have been able to define the test rules with the test classes themselves, but this is repetitive and does not seem very DRY.

Is it possible to define a per-test-method rule in the suite or must I add them to each and every test?

**Edit:** To clarify, I want to declare code in a suite that will run between (i.e. "around") the test methods in the test classes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be done, but it needs a bit of work. You need to define your own Suite runner and your own Test runner as well, and then override runChild() in the test runner. Using the following:

**AllTests.java:**

```
@RunWith(MySuite.class)
@SuiteClasses({Class1Test.class})
public class AllTests {
}
```

**Class1Test.java:**

```
public class Class1Test {
    @Deprecated @Test public void test1() {
        System.out.println("" + this.getClass().getName() + " test1");
    }

    @Test public void test2() {
        System.out.println("" + this.getClass().getName() + " test2");
    }
}
```

Note that I've annotated `test1()` with `@Deprecated`. You want to do something different when you have the `@Deprecated` annotation on the test, so we need to extend Suite to use a custom `Runner`:

```
public class MySuite extends Suite {
    // copied from Suite
    private static Class<?>[] getAnnotatedClasses(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        Suite.SuiteClasses annotation = klass.getAnnotation(Suite.SuiteClasses.class);
        if (annotation == null) {
            throw new InitializationError(String.format("class '%s' must have a SuiteClasses annotation", klass.getName()));
        }
        return annotation.value();
    }

    // copied from Suite
    public MySuite(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder) throws InitializationError {
        super(null, getRunners(getAnnotatedClasses(klass)));
    }

    public static List<Runner> getRunners(Class<?>[] classes) throws InitializationError {
        List<Runner> runners = new LinkedList<Runner>();

        for (Class<?> klazz : classes) {
            runners.add(new MyRunner(klazz));
        }

        return runners;
    }
}
```

JUnit creates a `Runner` for each test it will run. Normally, Suite would just create the default `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`, all we're doing here is overriding the constructor for the Suite which reads the classes from the `SuiteClass` annotation and we're creating our own runners with them, `MyRunner`. This is our MyRunner class:

```
public class MyRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
    public MyRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    protected void runChild(final FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
        Description description= describeChild(method);
        if (method.getAnnotation(Ignore.class) != null) {
            notifier.fireTestIgnored(description);
        } else {
            if (description.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class) != null) {
                System.out.println("name=" + description.getMethodName() + " annotations=" + description.getAnnotations());
            }
            runLeaf(methodBlock(method), description, notifier);
        }
    }
}
```

Most of this is copied from `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`. The bit I've added is:

```
if (description.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class) != null) {
    System.out.println("name=" + description.getMethodName() + " annotations=" + description.getAnnotations());
}
```

where we test for the existence of the `@Deprecated` annotation on the method, and do something if it's there. The rest is left as an exercise for the reader. When I run the above Suite, I get as output:

```
name=test1 annotations=[@java.lang.Deprecated(), @org.junit.Test(expected=class org.junit.Test$None, timeout=0)]
uk.co.farwell.junit.run.Class1Test test1
uk.co.farwell.junit.run.Class1Test test2
```

Please note that Suite has multiple constructors depending upon how it is invoked. The above works with Eclipse, but I haven't tested other ways of running the Suite. See the comments alongside the various constructors for Suite for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) that you add to the Suite. It doesn't give you everything a Rule can do, but it will provide you a Description class which should have the annotations available. At least, I don't think JUnit filters it down to its understood annotations only.

The developer of JUnit just discussed the mechanics of adding a RunListener to a Suite [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/junit/message/23727).

Answer (score 1):

By itself, adding a rule to the class annotated with `@RunWith(Suite.class)` won't do the trick. I believe this is because a `Suite` is a `ParentRunner<Runner>` rather than a `Runner` such as `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` which would attempt to scrape rules on the classes it runs. To run its children, it tells the child `Runners` to run. Those `Runner`s may have built up their tests by applying rules on those classes, but the `Suite` runner doesn't take any special action to apply rules from itself to the tests its child `Runner`s build.

Comment: So currently there is no way? Makes sense. I was wondering about the situation where an individual test would fail because it presumed resources set up by the suite. Also makes sense that a suite would just run the unit test as they are and not be able to hook *into* their life-cycle while still being able to hook in around it

Comment: I'd give @Yishai's suggestion a try, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use "test class hierarchy" ? I often use abstract test class to share test or fixture. For example, all my DB test are initialising an embedded datasource. I first create an abstract "DbTestCase" class which handles the init logic. Then all subclass will benefit the test and the fixtures.

However, sometimes I encounter problem when my test cases requires many test/fixture-logic that I can't store in a single hierarchy. In this case, only aspect programming solves the issue. Marking test/fixture-logic through specific annotation/interfaces that any required-class can implement.

You can optionnaly consider handling the "aspect" using a custom runner that will "inject" test/fixture-logic depending on annotation/interface of tested classes.

Comment: The hierarchy idea though is sound, but aspects are like black magic or wasabi: they should be used with great caution, and even then only sparingly.

Answer (score -1):

You can [group tests](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) with TestNG. And you can configure TestNG to run some logic [@BeforeGroup and @AfterGroup](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations).

Comment: I don't think that is what I am looking for. I want something that will run between each test.

Comment: But if you have a group of tests it should be possible to use BeforeMethod and AfterMethod. ( I guess )

Comment: Maybe, regardless, I need to use JUnit and TestNG is not an option.