# Extending Junit ParentRunner Class to filter test methods

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a requirement of reading a text file which contains list of all the testmethods in yes/no value and to pick the "yes" marked testmethods only for a  TestCase Class,and to execute in Junit.

So I have written a script to read the file and to group it in a **map<** TestCaseName,ArrayList_ofEnabledTestMethods **>** . To run that I found one option is to use **Assume.assumeTrue()**.

But I wanted to try some otherway...  instead of writting extra lines before each test methods , So I tried to write a custom runner (**ABCSuite** which extends **ParentRunner**) and planned to use it in my TestSuite file like below :

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(ABCSuite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({TestCalc.class})
public class BatTest{

}
```

Here TestCalc.class contains all the test methods some of which is marked "yes" in the earlier mentioned text file .

Please let me know how I can use of extending the **ParentRunner class/Junit Libraries**  to achieve this  . If any good tutorial is there or any link which addressed this before please.. share

Comment: Is your list of test methods the method names (test1) or a list of class name + method names (com.mycompany.foo.MyClass#test1)?

Comment: In the map<TestCaseName,ArrayList_ofEnabledTestMethods >

Comment: @Matthew Please ignore my earlier comment... below is the reply of your post ...In the map< **TestCaseName,ArrayList_ofEnabledTestMethods** >  the **ArrayList_ofEnabledTestMethods**  consists of only test method names like **test1**  .. (not the  class name + method names )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by extending [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html):

```
public class FilterRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
  private List<String> testsToRun = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "test1" });

  public FilterRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
    super(klass);
  }

  @Override
  protected void runChild(final FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
    Description description= describeChild(method);
    if (method.getAnnotation(Ignore.class) != null || !testsToRun.contains(method.getName())) {
      notifier.fireTestIgnored(description);
    } else {
      runLeaf(methodBlock(method), description, notifier);
    }
  }
}
```

You can fill in `testsToRun` as you like. The above will mark the other tests as Ignored. You use this like:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({Class1Test.class})
public class TestSuite {
}

@RunWith(FilterRunner.class)
public class Class1Test {
  @Test
  public void test1() {
    System.out.println("test1");
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() {
    System.out.println("test2");
  }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
test1
```

If you don't want to add the @FilterRunner to each test class, look at my answer to How to define [JUnit method rule in a suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639353/how-to-define-junit-method-rule-in-a-suite).

Comment: Matthew..Thanks  for the input.. but I want to run the FilterRunner  not for each test class but for a suite level , so your above [link] JUnit method rule in a suite? I tried  and found it expects a Test method in the suite itself and it runs only that with the given example (that extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner) , I modified the testsuite little adding a @Test method in it otherwise it was giving the intialization error

Comment: could please let me know how your solution ... of @FilterRunner would be applicable to a entire suite where it includes .... more that one test class which they have many test methods ... and those to be run selectively ( example **map< TestCaseName,ArrayList_ofEnabledTestMethods > **)...

Answer (score 2):

The JUnit way of implementing this would be an implementation of a [Filter](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/manipulation/Filter.html). It must be instantiated by the [Runner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Runner.html) that implements [Filterable](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/manipulation/Filterable.html). Filters are applied recursively through the tree of tests. So you only need to apply that filter once in your base suite.

You need to extend a runner and in the constructor apply the filter. To make things more flexible, you could configure the filters that should be applied with annotations.

I had the same requirement and that worked out well.