# Can we write custom testsuite in JUNIT 4?

Tags: java, junit4

I am new to JUNIT 4, I want to write code such as test suite get inputs from excelsheet and based on input testsuite invoke diffrent test cases. As per JUNIT 4 we can define all test cases in `@SuiteClasses({ ParameterSampleTest.class,SampleJUnitTest.class })` but this is when we have predefine test cases. but here i want to use custome JUNIT runner that takes decision based on input? can some one help to resolve this problem?

```
@RunWith(Suite.class) 
 public class AllTests {
  public static TestSuite suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(ParameterSampleTest.class));
        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(SampleJUnitTest.class));
        return suite;
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Priyank Shah

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: I am facing below error...java.lang.Exception: class 'com.example.junittest.AllTests' must have a SuiteClasses annotation

Comment: dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639353/how-to-define-junit-method-rule-in-a-suite

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
@RunWith(Suite.class) 
public class AllTests {
public static TestSuite suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        //if(your logic based decision) {
            suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(ParameterSampleTest.class));
        //}
        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(SampleJUnitTest.class));
        return suite;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error:  java.lang.Exception: class 'com.example.junittest.AllTests' must have a SuiteClasses annotation

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own test runner. It is not so difficult. You just have to create class that extends `org.junit.runner.Runner`and implement its `getDescription()` and `run()` methods. The runner may find sub-cases according to its business logic and run them.

Comment: Hi Alex, as per your comments i have write down the code.. but it is throwing an error now