# Allow Maven build to continue if a specific JUnit test fails

Tags: maven, junit, surefire

My Maven build uses JUnit tests with the Surefire plugin.  If a test fails, an `mvn install` will fail, which is normally desirable, but sometimes we wish to check in all the tests in advance for a feature which is not fully implemented.  We would like be able to specify certain tests as "known failures" which will log their failure but not stop the build.  Is there a way to do this?

(I'm aware we can set `testFailureIgnore` to true to not fail on any test failures, but we'd still like to fail on 'unexpected' test failures)

Comment: "Known failures" seems like a bad practice to me.

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174696/making-maven-run-all-tests-even-when-some-fail

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055022/mark-unit-test-as-an-expected-failure-in-junit ?