# JUnit custom Rule to run only on Annotated methods

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to create a custom rule in JUnit which only runs on test methods that I have a custom annotation on. The thing is I can't see a way to find out if the method wrapped in the Statement instance has the annotation set. I was thinking I could use reflection but how could I tell if the method in the Statement represents one of the annotated methods? Not really sure how to approach this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the instance of the Description class passed into the Statement. See the [javadoc for Description#getAnnotation()](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/runner/Description.html#getAnnotations()).

For more information, please see my answer to [Mark unit test as an expected failure in JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055022/mark-unit-test-as-an-expected-failure-in-junit/8092927#8092927).